# When yolov3 performs multi-scale training, will the anchor change according to the corresponding proportion?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

When yolov3 performs multi-scale training, will the anchors change according to the corresponding proportion?for example,when the input image size is resize to 608,expanded 608/416 times,then will scale of the anchors be automatically multiplied by 608/416? because the original scale of the anchors is corresponding to 416. Another question how to performs multi-scale training when using keras to train yolov3? please